# How do I automate pressing enter after sending keys into an element?

Tags: python, appium, appium-android, python-appium

**I am trying to:** 
Input a string into a search bar and press enter to search for it. I have already successfully sent the string into the search bar using `context.app.home_page.el_search_bar().send_keys("My String")`. I'm still searching for a way to let me press the enter key or search button for this search bar.

**I have tried:** 
1.A) In the `desired_caps`, I set `unicodeKeyboard` and `resetKeyboard` to `true` 
1.B) Used `context.driver.press_keycode(66)`

2)`context.driver.long_press_keycode(66)`

3)`context.driver.long_press_keycode(84)` 
 
Result: Above commands did not trigger any actions in the application.

**I am using:** Appium 1.22.3 | Python 3.10.8 | Pixel 6 Pro API 30 Virtual Device

When testing manually, typing the string into the search bar and pressing enter key on my keyboard does not work. The search only works when you press the [search button on the emulator keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiImn.jpg).

Comment: Have you tried using `context.app.home_page.el_search_bar().long_press_keycode(66)`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found something from [this thread](https://discuss.appium.io/t/unable-to-tap-search-button-on-android-softkeyboard/1598/26#:%7E:text=driver.execute_script(%E2%80%9Cmobile%3AperformEditorAction%E2%80%9D%2C%7B%E2%80%98action%E2%80%99%3A%E2%80%98search%E2%80%99%7D)).

This works for me: `context.driver.execute_script("mobile: performEditorAction", {'action': 'search'})`